# Django User Login Issue

Tags: python, django

I am back again with a Django Question. I am having issues with getting my login screen to work. I feel like maybe this is a simple issue that I am just not seeing. I am using the current versions of Python and Django. I am getting a NoReverseMatch error when trying to access my login page. Here is the code, along with some screen shots:

base.html:

```
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a> -
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a> -
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      Hello, {{ user.username }}.
    {% else %}
      <a href="{% url 'users:login' %}">log in</a>
    {% endif %}
</p>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

login.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% if form.errors %}
  <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
  {% endif %}

  <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}

      <button name="submit">log in</button>
      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}"/>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

users/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    # Login page
    #path('login/', LoginView, {'template_name': 'users/login.html'}, name='login'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html')),
]
```

[Code location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWwHf.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z6ZR.png)

Comment: You should add `, name='login'` in the `path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you commented out the `name='login'` part. Django can no longer find a [**`path(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path) with that name hence the error.

You should add the `name=…` parameter:

```
# users/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    # Login page
    path(
        'login/',
        LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),
        name='login'  # name of the path
    ),
]
```